# How to best handle copy-swap idiom with uninitialised memory

Tags: c++, c++11, memory, vector, deep-copy

As an academic exercise I created a custom vector implementation I'd like to support copying of non-pod types.

I would like the container to support storing elements that do not provide a default constructor.

When I reserve memory for the vector, and then push_back an element (which manages it's own resources and has a copy and assignment operator implemented - I'm ignoring move constructors for the moment) I have an issue using the copy-swap idiom for that type.

Because the swap happens on a type that is still uninitialised memory, after the swap, the destructor which is called for the temporary will attempt to free some piece of uninitialised data which of course blows up.

There are a few possible solutions I can see. One is ensure all non-pod types implement a default constructor and call that (placement new) on each element in the collection. I'm not a fan of this idea as it seems both wasteful and cumbersome.

Another is to memset the memory for the space of the type in the container to 0 before doing the swap (that way the temporary will be null and calling the destructor will operate without error). This feels kind of hacky to me though and I'm not sure if there is a better alternative (see the code below for an example of this) You could also memset all the reserved space to 0 after calling reserve for a bunch of elements but again this could be wasteful.

Is there documentation on how this is implemented for std::vector as calling reserve will not call the constructor for allocated elements, whereas resize will (and for types not implementing a default constructor a constructed temporary can be passed as a second parameter to the call)

Below is some code you can run to demonstrate the problem, I've omitted the actual vector code but the principle remains the same.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

// Dumb example type - not something to ever use
class CustomType {
public:
    CustomType(const char* info) {
        size_t len = strlen(info) + 1;
        info_ = new char[len];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
            info_[i] = info[i];
        }
    }

    CustomType(const CustomType& customType) {
        size_t len = strlen(customType.info_) + 1;
        info_ = new char[len];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
            info_[i] = customType.info_[i];
        }
    }

    CustomType& operator=(CustomType customType) {
        swap(*this, customType);
        return *this;
    }

    void swap(CustomType& lhs, CustomType& rhs) {
        std::swap(lhs.info_, rhs.info_);
    }

    ~CustomType() {
        delete[] info_;
    }

    char* info_;
};

int main() {
    CustomType customTypeToCopy("Test");

    // Mimics one element in the array - uninitialised memory
    char* mem = (char*)malloc(sizeof(CustomType));

    // Cast to correct type (would be T for array element)
    CustomType* customType = (CustomType*)mem;  
    // If memory is cleared, delete[] of null has no effect - all good
    memset(mem, 0, sizeof(CustomType));
    // If the above line is commented out, you get malloc error - pointer 
    // being freed, was not allocated

    // Invokes assignment operator and copy/swap idiom
    *customType = customTypeToCopy;

    printf("%s\n", customType->info_);
    printf("%s\n", customTypeToCopy.info_);

    return 0;
}
```

Any information/advice would be greatly appreciated!

Solved!

Thank you to @Brian and @Nim for helping me understand the use case for when assignment (copy/swap) is valid.

To achieve what I wanted I simply needed to replace the line

```
*customType = customTypeToCopy;
```

with

```
new (customType) CustomType(customTypeToCopy);
```

Invoking the copy constructor not the assignment operator!

Thanks!

Comment: I've read this question a couple of times (may be it's late) but it's not clear whether you are having a problem implementing the swap for the *custom type* or the *vector*? (btw. I don't think `memset()` will work) And it's not clear where the copy-swap with unitialized memory kicks in (implies you are trying to access an element that is outside of the "bounds" of your vector...)

Comment: Hey Nim! Sorry if my explanation isn't great, I'll try and clarify. Basically when doing the swap the, info_ pointer that is sitting in uninitialised memory value gets moved into the temporary that I pass into that function, and then when the scope ends, the destructor is called on that temporary, but the info_ pointer is just garbage, so calling delete[] causes a crash. If I memset the memory before, it will be null, and calling delete has no effect. I just want to know if this is an okay thing to do or bad practice. I can't think of a good alternative :(

Comment: ...but that implies you are *swapping* with an element that is *out-of-bounds* (i.e. beyond the *size* of the vector..)

Comment: No I've allocated space for it (see the example code) it is just uninitialised so anything could be in that space because no constructor has been called and I haven't zeroed the memory (unless I do call memset). You can copy and paste the code into ideone to have a look at what it's doing and what happens if you comment out the memset line if that'd help.

Comment: ..I understand - but what you are modelling is a case where you are swapping with an object that has not been constructed - this is invalid. You cannot swap with an object that has not been constructed (in the context of your vector, you are accessing an element outside of it's bounds - i.e. one that has not been constructed - reserving storage is *not the same* as constructing an object...)

Comment: Ah okay I see what you're saying... that makes sense! Thanks! So then how the hell does std::vector work then when you reserve a bunch of space and then push_back an element? It doesn't call the constructor on those elements initially during reserve as you can use std::vector with objects without a default constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use copy-and-swap for construction.

You use copy-and-swap for assignment in order to solve the following problem: the left side of the assignment is an already-initialized object, so it needs to free the resources it holds before having the right side's state copied or moved into it; but if the copy or move construction fails by throwing an exception, we want to keep the original state.

If you're doing construction rather than assignment---because the target is uninitialized---the problem solved by copy-and-swap doesn't exist. You just invoke the constructor with placement new. If it succeeds, great. If it fails by throwing an exception, the language guarantees that any subobjects already constructed are destroyed, and you just let the exception propagate upward; in the failure case the state of the target will be the same as it was before: uninitialized.

Comment: Ah okay I see - so my problem then becomes what if that object does not have a default constructor? I take it I need to call placement new on that element but what if I want to call a specific constructor. Is there a way to do that? How does std::vector handle this case when you call reserve on it and then push_back elements? Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: @Tom `vector::push_back` uses the copy or move constructor. If the type cannot be copied or moved, you can't have a vector of it (or at least you can't `push_back` into it).

Comment: Ah okay I see, thank you Brian! I've got my solution! :) If I understand correctly I just need to update the code so instead of doing as assignment I do this - new (customType) CustomType(customTypeToCopy); Thank you very much!! :)

Comment: @Tom You might also want to add an rvalue overload for `push_back` and use `std::move`